# Woocommerce API get product prices as customer

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

We have a webshop that has different pricing for certain customers (certain customers might have 15% off certain product categories).

I'm making orders using the Woocommerce API, but when placing an order the pricing is based on the user that created the consumer key and secret (if I place a discount on products on this account, I can see the discounted price). And out of the box Woocommerce doesn't allow customers to create API keys.

So I'm looking for a way to access the products as if I'm a certain user. Something like

`https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/{product_id}?customer_id={customer_id}`

or

`https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/customers/{customer_id}/products/...`

But I do not know where to start to create something like this...

Answer (score 1):

Doing this with a CURL isn't going to happen, Unless its natively supported by the team, This will have to be a implementation on your application, So you have a way of knowing which users get what discounts im guessing? So cant you just assign something like a Tag to that user Called E.G 15% discount then on your checkout process check threw the users tags if a Discount Tag is Present apply the discount?

Comment: The problem is knowing which users get which discount on which product (categories). So the tag solution would require multiple tags on a single user for different product categories.

That's why I thought that perhaps it would be possible to create an custom endpoint that can look up what the price is for an product for specific user.

Comment: What are your variables in this regards like If user is account was created 6 months ago They get 15% or what. Have look at this https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/22974
I'd for sure say this is going to have to be a internal service, Or maybe Theres some Plugin you can use for discounts that has its own APi that extends the woo-commerce api

Comment: Some might be resellers, others might be endusers. But these customers have existed before we had a webshop. So discounts vary wildly between them sometimes simple because they asked for more discounts and we could give it to them.  
For now I have gone a different route, in our external app customers select the products they want, and with a click they get redirected to webshop with the products in the shopping cart. This way I will keep handling all the orders in the webshop. Only downside is they can't see their prices in the app before placing them in the cart.